# How do I click the first item in a spinner using Robotium?

Tags: android, spinner, robotium

I am having problems scrolling up in a spinner to select the first item in a Robotium test case. Here is my code:

```
int pos = solo.getCurrentSpinners().get(0).getSelectedItemPosition();
solo.pressSpinnerItem(0, 0 - pos);
```

pos is 1 when I debug, but Robotium still presses the spinner on index 1 even though I order it to press on -1. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Markus

Comment: I submitted a bug report: http://code.google.com/p/robotium/issues/detail?id=276. Let's see what happens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems they took those classes out now.  Just ran into this myself but found a way to do this properly and generically.

```
// 0 is the first spinner in the layout
View view1 = solo.getView(Spinner.class, 0);
solo.clickOnView(view1);
solo.scrollToTop(); // I put this in here so that it always keeps the list at start
// select the 10th item in the spinner
solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(TextView.class, 10));
```

Comment: The final clicking on the `TextView` for the spinner will of course only work correctly if there are no other `TextView`s in the UI, am I right?

Comment: That is what the getView(TextView.class, 0) does by the number designated.  I would assume if your spinner has multiple textviews you'd have to figure which one it is that is the clickable.  In that case I would use a layout as clickable.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. `solo.getView(T view, int instance)` searches the _whole_ view tree for instances of `T`, so if you happen to have regular `TextView`'s before the spinner, hard-coding this number in a test is really error-prone, no?

Answer (score -1):

are you able just to get the view and call the perform click on it?

```
solo.getCurrentSpinners().get(0).performClick()
```

Comment: that does not work for me. Using Robotium 4.1 I don't even see a getCurrentSpinners.

Comment: Yeah, they removed this function. It probably worked fine in the latest version when Frank answered the question.

Answer (score -1):

The API to use here with Robotium is rather flaky, so I decided to go down the direct API route:

```
instrumentation.runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) solo.getView(resourceId);
        spinner.setSelection(position, true);
    }
});
```

This won't show you the popup of the Spinner, but it will select the desired item.