# Robotium : Getting number of items in spinner?

Tags: view, spinner, robotium

I'm a QA, and I'm new to android automation as such, and I am having problem in automating the spinner / Dropdown related activities in my app. I am using Robotium 4.1 for my automation.

The Spinner in my app is implemented using actionbarsherlock. The Hierarchyviewer shows it as `Popupwindow:SOME-RANDOM-ID`. It looks like the implementation is internal to actionbarsherlock. After talking to the dev he tells me that it's a "non-visible" element. I don't understand what that means, because I can see the element.

Also, I can't find the methods mentioned in some of the other questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921036/how-do-i-click-the-first-item-in-a-spinner-using-robotium).

I suppose the right way is to use `solo.getViews()`, and `solo.getCurrentViews` etc. but I don't know how to use the parameters in there, so whatever I tried didn't work.

Can someone guide me with a detailed example? (including how to give the parameters to getViews etc will be much appreciated.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to get number of items:

```
mSpinner.getAdapter().getCount();
```

How to click on specified item on spinner:

```
solo.pressSpinnerItem(indexOfSpinner, indexOfItem);
```

How to get current spinners:

```
ArrayList<Spinner> currentSpinners = solo.getCurrentViews(Spinner.class);
```

How to get spinner with specified index:

```
Spinner spinner = getView(Spinner.class, index);
```

Comment: Thanks maszter. Related questions,                                            1) mSpinner.getAdapter.getCount ->  How to define the mSpinner object? 2) pressSpinnerItem -> I think this method is deprecated Robotium 4.1 onwards. Eclipse now asks to use either getView and getCurrentViews only. and I'm little bit unaware of how to use these 2 methods right.

Comment: As I wrote:
Spinner mSpinner = getView(Spinner.class, index);
It's not deprecated, look at current sources:
https://github.com/jayway/robotium/blob/master/robotium-solo/src/main/java/com/jayway/android/robotium/solo/Solo.java#L902

Comment: Thanks, it worked after several tries. :) I was actually providing actionbarsherlock class there, instead of "Spinner.class". Thanks again for your help!

Comment: This code works too!                                                                     Spinner myView = solo.getView(Spinner.class, 0); 
solo.clickOnView(myView);
solo.clickOnText("I want to click on this");