# Select Item of Spinner error in Robotium

Tags: android, robotium, android-testing, ui-testing

I make a UI Test that contains a `Spinner`. When I execute:

```
  solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(R.id.spinner_editwebsite));
```

The spinner can show the options,but can not select the options then the test stopped!

Then an error occurred!

I try to add

```
`solo.pressSpinnerItem(0,1);`
```

behind the

```
`solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(R.id.spinner_editwebsite));`
```

but not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this answer:

> Seems they took those classes out now.  Just ran into this myself but
> found a way to do this properly and generically.
>
> ```
> // 0 is the first spinner in the layout
> View view1 = solo.getView(Spinner.class, 0);
> solo.clickOnView(view1);
> solo.scrollToTop(); // I put this in here so that it always keeps the list at start
> // select the 10th item in the spinner
> solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(TextView.class, 10));
> ```
>
> From: [How do I click the first item in a spinner using Robotium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921036/how-do-i-click-the-first-item-in-a-spinner-using-robotium)

As you can see a method which you try to use seems to be depracated.
Try to use code above instead of yours.

Hope it help

Comment: not wrok it can only show items,but can not select the items